# SHA256 encryption and decryption (Python 2.7) - same word but different hash

Tags: python, encryption, hash, sha256, sha

I wanted to write a script that can encrypt and decrypt words. But I ran on a problem and cannot understand it. This code I used to encrypt is this:

```
 def encrypt():
    print "Enter string for encryption: \n"
    rec = raw_input()
    enkr =hashlib.sha256(rec).hexdigest()
    print enkr
```

and code I am using to decrypt based on dictionary is this:

```
def decrypt():
    print "Enter hash for decryption: \n"
    rec = raw_input()
    print "Enter path of wordlist"
    list = raw_input()
    wordl=open(list,"r")
    wordk = wordl.readlines()
    for w in wordk:
        w = hashlib.sha256(w).hexdigest()
        if rec.lower() != w:
            print "Not this " + w
        elif rec.lower() ==w:
            print "Found ! " + w
            break
        else:
            print "Nothing found ! "
```

For example let's say i want to encrypt word "admin". I get this hash 8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
and when i want to decrypt i get this 
fc8252c8dc55839967c58b9ad755a59b61b67c13227ddae4bd3f78a38bf394f7
and my question is, why am i getting two different hash with same function? Best regards, Khan

Comment: The backtick-based syntax is for code-formatting strings less than a line long. For multi-line blocks, use the `{}` button in the editor after selecting your code to indent each line by four spaces, or add those spaces yourself.

Comment: Don't describe what you're doing as 'encrypting' and 'decrypting' because it's both wrong and confusing. And make sure to strip the newlines from the end of the strings you get out of `readlines`, readlines includes them, raw_input does not

Comment: SHA 256 is not encryption.

Comment: Print `repr(yourstring)` to get your string in a completely unambiguous form. If the hash differs, the `repr()` of the original value presumably will as well.

Comment: *nod*. I think there's a good question hidden in here somewhere, but it's something like "Why does an input string have a different hash when read with raw_input() vs readlines()?" -- in short, it's a question one gets to after doing more initial diagnosis than is as of yet included.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is one of those questions of near-infinite dupes.

Comment: ...all the more reason it should be further reduced -- to be unambiguously such a duplicate, and thus used as a means to redirect folks to the best/canonical instance and answer set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8c69…a918` is the SHA256 hash of `"admin"`.

`fc82…94f7` is the SHA256 hash of `"admin\n"`.

`file.readlines()` includes a trailing newline at the end of each line it reads. To remove that, you can use `w.rstrip("\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

`rec = raw_input()` doesn't have a newline in it.

On the other hand, each line iterated upon by `for w in wordk:` has a trailing newline.

So you have to `rstrip("\n")` your lines or use `splitlines()` to get rid of the last newline character before performing the hash.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.